# Store multiple submissions from a modal template

Tags: knockout.js

### [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/DsbEG/1/)

*I'm still leaning knockout.js so feel free to make suggestions on improving my code*

---

I'm using `ko.mapping` to generate my view model from a JSON string containing the following structure:

```
questions: [
    answer: "whetever the user enters", 
    controlType: "the type of input to display",
    lookupItems: "anything that will go into a SELECT input",
    modalSection: "if this question is a modal, then all modal questions will go here"
]
```

I've managed to get everything working OK, and by [following this example of handling modals](http://aboutcode.net/2012/11/15/twitter-bootstrap-modals-and-knockoutjs.html) managed to get my modal and respective questions popping up as I wanted.

My problem however, is how do I save multiple results from this modal?  The user should be able to bring up the modal many times and add as much information as they want - this should then be shown underneath the question.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Add a `.submissions` array to the `modalSection`**

Extend my `.modalSection` to have a submissions collection on it, so when the user clicks *OK* on the modal, it adds a copy of the current modal to this collection, which should then show in my table:

```
<!-- ko foreach: modalSection.submissions -->
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: questions">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: text"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: answer"></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**[Here's a version of my fiddle trying this](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/DsbEG/2/)**

This doesn't seem to work however, my table remains unpopulated. Even then, if I did get this working am I even going in the right direction - won't I just be storing the same observable instance of `modalSection` multiple times?

Can anyone point me in the right direction, and perhaps take a look at the code in the provided fiddle and give any pointers on what I can improve and how to get to where I want to be?

---

## Edit 1

To try and give a better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve here's a scenario.

Say there are two questions:

1. Have you ever owned a car?
2. Please give details of all cars you've owned, including make, model and colour.

So my first question would be a drop down list (where the `lookupItems` are [Yes] and [No]). The second question requires more detail, so it makes it a prime candidate for a modal, so this question would have a button as its input perhaps labelled [Add Cars].

This would bring up a modal with the questions (that have control types etc. just like non-modal questions) [What is the make of the car?], [What is the model?] and [What is the colour?]. Once the modal is filled in, the results will be populated somewhere (like a table) and the [Add Cars] button would be available again to add N more details.

Comment: I don't really get what the `modalSection` part does. Are only some of the question going to be modal? I can't even think of what that would look like.

Comment: @Tyrsius the `modalSection` is basically an object that groups together questions to appear on the modal. If the `controlType` of the question is a ModalTable then the `modalSection` contains the questions for the modal.

Comment: Ok, I have a working fiddle for you. You have a lot of errors though, and I don't know if you want me to cover them all. Would you like the short answer, or the long one?

Comment: @Tyrsius oh definitely the long one, if it's constructive :o)

Comment: I added a completely re-worked fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I start, I want to say that I think that guide fails in it's goal of separating DOM manipulation from the viewmodel. There are several instances of DOM access

```
var hiddenDiv = document.createElement('div');
    hiddenDiv.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(hiddenDiv);
...
$(hiddenDiv).remove();
...
$rendered.dialog('close');
```

All of which break our separation of concerns. There are ways to accomplish this, but it means completely overhauling your code. I'll come back to this.

**Problems with your code** (Solutions below)

1. the section in your HTML that starts with `<!-- ko if: modalSection.submissions -->` loops over `"foreach: modalSection.questions"`. The problem here is that it will not display the collection of `submissions`, which is where you are sticking the results of the modal. Even if you put the results in correctly, they won't display.
2. Your are collecting your JSON from the HTML. This is not sparta, this is madness.
3. In the dialog OK, you are adding `submissions` as an observableArray. This won't work, because Knockout has already applied the bindings for the viewmodel.
4. You are `push`ing the result of your dialog onto the array *inside* the observable, which will not raise observable changes
5. You are not *copying* the dialog result, your are just adding it to `submissions`

**Solutions for your code**

1. You will need two loops here. An outer loop for `submissions`, and an inner loop for `questions`.
2. I am guessing your server is sticking this JSON into the HTML somehow. Solutions for specific servers will vary, but you should be able to stick the JSON into a `script` tag, store it in a variable, and then use it directly. The DOM is not for data.
3. You will need to have a `submissions` property in the original JSON so that Knockout mapping will create an observableArray for you *before* the original apply bindings.
4. Add to observable array's like this: `submissions.push(item)`. `push` is on the observable *before* the parens, not after.
5. Make a copy. `ko.toJS` will unwrap an observable viewmodel and stick in a standard javascript object for you. You can then call `ko.mapping.fromJS` on this, and you have a clean copy.

## [The working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/5hHyw/).

**Further Notes**

There is still the problem of the dialog results not being reset. You can handle this in a couple way, but what I really encourage you to do look into other ways to handle dialogs such that your aren't messing with HTML in your viewmodel. Ryan Niemeyer has a great fiddle demonstrating a [jQuery dialog](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/SnPdE/) being used by a viewmodel. It's basic, but it should point you in the right direction.

---

## Edit

Here is [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/j2CqX/2/), heavily re-worked. There is zero DOM access in the viewmodels, I am using Niemeyer's dialog binding to talk to the modal. I am not using the mapping plugin because I think it makes you work harder when your viewmodels have behavior.

Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: The JSON is retrieved through an asmx web service, it was just hard-coded for simplicity in the fiddle. The re-worked version looks very interesting, I'll need some time to digest this, but having a quick play it does exactly what I need it to do, now I just need to understand it.

Comment: Thanks by the way, very much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, just let me know if you need any part of it explained. It's always worth the extra effort when the person asking shows the same.

Comment: This is great! Managed to get it working in practice, and the custom bindings have taught me loads more about Knockout. Thanks again!